# How do I make a block able to be oriented (Minecraft 1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm experimenting with making my own Resource Pack for an urban world in Minecraft 1.13.1
My first new block texture is a worn asphalt with a white stripe on the side - for use in creating roads and car parks. So you get plain surface on top if you click on a horizontal surface when placing, and the stripe when you click on a vertical surface.
I made it as a re-texture of pink_concrete (which I'm unlikely to use!), with json files in models/block/ to set the textures and blockstates/ to set the variants, in both cases working from one of the log blocks as an example.

```
{
"parent": "block/cube_column",
"textures": {
    "end": "block/gray_concrete",
    "side": "block/pink_concrete"
}
```

}

The textures work but I can still only place the block in top-up orientation.
When I apply the textures to Jungle wood instead, it works as intended. I had thought that setting the parent to cube_column and defining the axes would be sufficient to make it orientable, but clearly I have missed a step somewhere?

There aren't any "spare" orientable blocks that I'm willing to sacrifice - using Jungle Wood was just a test.

[Edited to explain more thoroughly]

Comment: I think it is because Pink Concrete is not orientable, but Jungle Wood is. Try with another block that is orientable and another that is not, if the result is the same, you likely have your answer!

Comment: You used the [tag:mods] tag. Do you actually use mods and if yes, how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: Mods tag removed - I was using it in the general sense since this SE is not minecraft-specific. Didn't think there'd be a resource packs tag

Comment: @Ckankonmange - but my question is specifically what change it is that makes a block orientable. As per my edit, there aren't any orientable blocks that I'm willing to reskin.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know this is old, but in case you still are wondering, I have a little bit of feedback. This is more like what needs to happen, not how to make it happen, as I am rather inexperienced with this kind of thing. I believe you need to define variants of the block in the blockstates json file (if there is one in resource packs, I only know about modding, but I assume there is one). The variant that exists by default is just "normal." However, you need 3 variants: axis=x, axis=y, and axis=z. There is also axis=none but I don't think that it is required. (I found this information on an old Minecraft Forums modding thread [here)](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2476627-rendering-custom-log-block-metadata-blockstates)

Furthermore, you need a way to find which way the block is facing. There is a bit on how to do that in the thread above and can probably be found by investigating the code. Unfortunately, this is where I am not certain, but there is some info on blockstates in the Minecraft Wiki [here.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model)

As you can probably tell, I am not the most competent person to help, but I figured that even a little bit could help a bit and maybe you could figure out what you need to do. Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: you could use a debug stick and right click to orient the block. eg. north, south, east, west